# How to use verbatim strings with interpolation?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0, verbatim-string

In C# 6 there is a new feature: interpolated strings. These let you put expressions directly into code.

Rather than relying on indexes:

```
string s = string.Format("Adding \"{0}\" and {1} to foobar.", x, this.Y());
```

the above becomes:

```
string s = $"Adding \"{x}\" and {this.Y()} to foobar.";
```

However, we have a lot of strings across multiple lines using verbatim strings (mainly SQL statements) like this:

```
string s = string.Format(@"Result...
Adding ""{0}"" and {1} to foobar:
{2}", x, this.Y(), x.GetLog());
```

Reverting these to regular strings seems messy:

```
string s = "Result...\r\n" +
$"Adding \"{x}\" and {this.Y()} to foobar:\r\n" +
x.GetLog().ToString();
```

How to use both verbatim and interpolated strings together?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can apply both `$` and `@` prefixes to the same string:

```cs
string s = $@"Result...
Adding ""{x}"" and {this.Y()} to foobar:
{x.GetLog()}";
```

When [introduced in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14), *interpolated verbatim strings* had to start with the tokens `$@`, [but starting with C# 8, you can use either `$@` or `@$`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters).

Since C#11 we also have [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals), which give you a better way for large blocks like this.

Instead of `@` you can use `"""`, and you can still combine it with `$`:

```cs
string s = $"""
    Result...
    Adding "{x}" and {this.Y()} to foobar:
    {x.GetLog()}
    """;
```

This will produce the same output as the first example, but it's more readable. The C# compiler will strip any whitespace before the closing `"""` from every line, so the string can have the same indent as your code.

Comment: The link to the C# 8 explanation has changed.  Microsoft took out the explanations and replaced with direct links to the detail pages.