# How to insert a variable into a long string with multiple quotation marks and escape characters?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, escaping

I have this really miserable line of code I need to work with that I haven't found a better way to do. My issue is I'm trying to get a variable inserted in the middle of this string, so normally I would just concatenate with +, but in this case the huge amount of quotation marks and escape characters have made this awful to try to do logistically. If anyone knows a simpler way of doing this I'd appreciate it- I'm sure there's an easy solution but I just can't get it. Here's the line:

`Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ", @"""C:\Thunder\Scripts\script.ps1"" ""VARIABLE""");`

So what I'm trying to do is put a string variable where the VARIABLE text is here. When I try to break it apart to concat, the combination of the `@`, the `"s`, and the `\'s`, I can't get the string apart in such a way that I can concat the variable into it. I assume there's an easier way here that I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638579/how-to-use-verbatim-strings-with-interpolation

Comment: Thank you @DzianisKarpuk for the link. I tried to search for this first, but not knowing what exact search terms to use, I didn't find that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
$@"""C:\Thunder\Scripts\script.ps1"" ""{variable}""";
```

Using the `$` prefix allows variables to be inserted using curly brackets, which will reduce the number of quotations in your case.

---

If `variable` is not a string, an implicit `ToString()` is called on the object instead.

Comment: It looks like this worked! I'll need to run some tests to make sure it's behaving as expected, but so far it's looking good! Thanks for the assist, this saves me a lot of headaches. Programming is kind of a tertiary role at the job so I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: And testing confirmed, works perfectly. Thanks again.